# 'WANDB_MODE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pytorch, wandb

I am trying to run the custom [yolo model](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5) on my data set in my local machine. I am following some reference code from the kaggle platform. Here first time I encounter the `wandb` frame work. while doing so I use the following to run the `train.py`  file in my jupyter lab.

```
!WANDB_MODE="dryrun" python train.py --img 640 --batch 16 --epochs 30 --data D:/Anil/Shawn_Research/Iamge_DataSet/VinBigData/New_Direct/vinbigdata.yaml --weights yolov5x.pt --cache
```

This work fine on the kaggle platform but in my local machine it shows following:

```
'WANDB_MODE' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

While reading the similar thread I realized I might making mistake related to path variable or Environment variable.
Even I tried to get solution from the [official document](https://docs.wandb.ai/library/environment-variables) but couldn't figure out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the kernel that you're following? The official kernel has been updated and you can now easily authenticate using the prompter. If you'd still like to disable wandb from syncing data to the cloud, you can do either of these:

1. Use environment variable:
   In a kernel execute this.

```
import os
os.environ['WANDB_MODE'] = 'offline'
```

2. run `!wandb offline` in a kernel cell